# Imported OBJ looks weird on EEVEE perfectly fine on Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I made this head in cinema 4d and export it as on OBJ file to Blender.

It looks weird on EEVEE but ok on Cycles
I thought it is because of normal or dublicate mesh but after flipping normals, clear sharp edges, using weld modifier and merge by distance it didnt solve

Blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qXmqt0AClGvnY3Sr3P3D3Bf-WyvC7ith/view?usp=sharinghttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1qXmqt0AClGvnY3Sr3P3D3Bf-WyvC7ith/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your material settings are set to *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* (and *Show Backface* is activated), switch to *Opaque*:

[image]

Comment: thank you man
how fast ✌✌

Comment: you're welcome  ;)